# Typescript - require AMD module like a namespace

Tags: requirejs, typescript, amd

To use Typescript with requireJs, I made two *export* classes in a common *export* module. This allows me to load them with *requireJs* like that:

```
require(["class1", "class2"], function (_class1, _class2) {
    var x = new _class1.mymodule.class1();
    var y = new _class2.mymodule.class2();
}
```

Here is an example of one of those *class*-files

```
export module mymodule {
    export class class1 {
        //some props and functions
    }
}
```

After long research, I didn't figured out how to reference just the module in a way like that:

```
// not working code ahead:
require(["class1", "class2"], function (mymodule) {
    var x = new mymodule.class1();
    var y = new mymodule.class2();
}
```

The last code block is plain javascript in a *script* HTML-tag.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing

```
export module mymodule {
    export class class1 {
        //some props and functions
    }
}
```

Write this

```
export class class1 {
    //some props and functions
}
```

There's no need to wrap up your classes in a namespace with external modules, because the importer of them can decide which name they are referred to by. See also the "[Needless Namespacing](https://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Modules%20in%20TypeScript)" section of the TypeScript documentation.

Comment: This works fine, if you put all your classes in one `.ts` file. But what would you do, when you want to import `class1.ts` and `class2.ts` into one dependency variable like "mymodule"?

Comment: You can't, regardless of whether or not you use `export module mymodule {`

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is not what I imagined, but it works for me as a solution. Here is what I figured out:

- **Don't** use `export` on internal dependencies like *class1*, *class2*
- If you need *class2* inside *class1*, just reference the typescript file with `<reference path="class2" />` to get the declarations for *TSLint*
- Create one wrapper typescript-file and references all dependencies like so:

**wrapper.ts**

```
/// <reference path="test/class1.ts" />
/// <amd-dependency path="class1" />
/// <reference path="test/class2.ts" />
/// <amd-dependency path="class2" />

export var class1: class1;
export var class2: class2;
```

**javascript block**

```
require(["wrapper"], function () {
    // do something with the dependencies
    var x = new class1();
}
```